# Clicking external links(ex: in skype) always opens them in chrome incognito mode. How to change this?(Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: google-chrome, links, private-browsing

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Currently clicking a web link from a 3rd party app will open the chrome incognito window.
How can I change this as chrome settings doesn't seem to have anything related to this.

Thanks.